# PostgreSQL - can we use one schema table in another schema function if both the tables are having same no.of columns with same datatype

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL

Can we use one schema table in another schema function if both the tables are having same no.of columns with same datatype

Comment: sure - why not?..

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
t=# create schema so51;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# create schema so52;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# create table so51.so53(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create function so52.so54() returns int as $$begin return coalesce((select i from so51.so53),42); end;$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select so52.so54();
 so54
------
   42
(1 row)

t=# insert into so51.so53 select 19;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select so52.so54();
 so54
------
   19
(1 row)
```

Comment: can u pls send me ur mail i will send my code i have 1 question

Comment: Vao Tsun  
can u pls send me ur mail

Comment: there's no problem with having not working code - ask a question (just as you did hour ago)

Comment: in my function my input parameters are getting inserted to 1 table with 1 schema after inserting data in to tht table iam writing update statement for updating tht table data into another table with another schema is it correct

Comment: there's a blue button on the top left with "Ask Question" - take a look at the top of the page

Comment: i have a function having input paramers inserting data into xch.xch_transmas_patient table after inserting data into xch.xch_transmas_patient table iam trying to update data into lt_transmas_patient table by writing update statement and iam using 1 common table in which both schemas data are inserting

Comment: it is telling once every 90 mins only we can post

Comment: please spend those 90 minutes on thinking your next question, so you would not have to wait another 90

Comment: u can send me ur mail id na

Comment: i can send my question to ur mail id without waiting for 90 mins

Comment: ah! that's an idea